# How to get flutter to open in terminal zsh on mac monteray

Tags: flutter, macos, terminal

Flutter opened and moved to developer folder. I haven't had any luck updating the flutter path in the terniaml. It fails to open flutter

I enter the info posted on the flutter website and replace the path with my info on where the flutter folder is located on my computer.  i run, source $HOME/.. Then a error code comes back.  If i run,

```
 echo $PATH
```

then it comes back flutter not detected.

Comment: try this: `Delete /flutter/bin/cache/artifacts` directory and run flutter doctor in terminal

Answer (score 0):

According to the installing Flutter documentation, you should put the downloaded folder in the `development` folder, not the `developer` folder. Try moving the downloaded folder to the `development` folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to update the path via the terminal. Just do it manually.

Steps to manually update the path:

1. Since you already know you have a zsh terminal. Go to /Users/[your username]. Unhide the files by hitting [cmd+shift+.].
2. If you don't have a .zshrc file. Just create a new file. You can download my .zshrc file from here: [.zshrc file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WCTvPnOrLPgYsTLI_1iZvi8hQXrvkPl8/view?usp=share_link)
3. open it in TextEdit and write this
   `export PATH="$PATH:/Users/syedsadiquh/Development/SDKs/flutter/bin"`
   After the $PATH: just replace it with your own flutter/bin location.
4. Now close all terminal windows to source the new file automatically.

Now verify your path by running `echo $PATH` 
Now verify that flutter is available by running `which flutter`.

The official flutter docs to refer (see update your path section): [Official flutter docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos#update-your-path)